# keeps failing installing aif360 package in Pycharm

Tags: numpy, installation, pycharm, package, subprocess

I'm trying to install AIF360 package in Pycharm,

but whatever I try, either on command line or pycharm's own package managing system,

it keeps failing with this message:

```
    Collecting aif360
      Using cached aif360-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (175 kB)
    Collecting scikit-learn>=0.22.1
      Using cached scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (7.2 MB)
    Collecting pandas>=0.24.0
      Using cached pandas-1.4.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (10.6 MB)
    Collecting scipy<1.6.0,>=1.2.0
      Using cached scipy-1.5.4.tar.gz (25.2 MB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: still running...
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
    
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1
      
      [2450 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-60.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.18
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.17.3
        Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting pybind11>=2.4.3
        Using cached pybind11-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (211 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
      
        [1938 lines of output]
        Running from numpy source directory.
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\projectname\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
      
        blis_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\projectname\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
      
        ...
        get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
        customize GnuFCompiler
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        ...
        customize PGroupFlangCompiler
        Could not locate executable flang
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
          NOT AVAILABLE
      
        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users...
NOT AVAILABLE
      
        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        ...
      
       ...
Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\multiarray\arraytypes.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\multiarray\arraytypes.obj
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\umath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\projectname\venv\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tcnumpy\core\src\multiarray\array_assign_scalar.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\numpy\core\src\multiarray\array_assign_scalar.obj
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\umath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\projectname\venv\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tcnumpy\core\src\multiarray\array_assign_array.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\numpy\core\src\multiarray\array_assign_array.obj
     ...Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalartypes.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.1\numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalartypes.obj" failed with exit status 2
        [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
      
      Encountered error while trying to install package.
      
      numpy
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1
    
    See above for output.
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I've tried uninstall-reinstalling numpy, tried both command line and Pycharm's own package manager, but none of them worked.

How can I resolve this?

Here are the things I've tried so far:

- command-line installation outside of Pycharm works fine
  ** but not affecting the Pycharm project
- Anaconda package installation works fine
  ** but also not affecting the Pycharm project
- command-line installation inside of Pycharm fails with error
- in-Pycharm package manager fails with the same error
- Removing the NumPy package and reinstalling it did not change anything
- Individually installing NumPy other than with aif360 did not change anything
- I'm a Windows user - and installing Microsoft C++ Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 did not change anything
- Cannot uninstall aif360 package neither in pycharm command line or anaconda... takes forever, solving package specification and environment longer than 30 mins

Answer (score 0):

For those who have faced the same issue,
I was able to resolve it by changing the python interpreter version to the matching one, which was surprisingly 3.1, which has to be at least 3.5 by requirement.
You can change the interpreter version either by creating a new project or in the settings in Pycharm.